# IE9 formatting issue when editing question

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, internet-explorer-9

I was editing a question earlier on SO in IE9 and while adding tags, this is how it appears.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Marking as declined -- we don't support visual glitches for this version of IE.